# Dictionary reduce data python

Tags: python, python-2.7, dictionary, zip

I just writing my code to load a data (ex:`iris.data`) so i write my code as this:

```
data = [l.strip() for l in open('iris.data')]
features = [tuple(map(float, x.split(',')[:-1])) for x in data]
labels = [x.split(',')[-1] for x in data]
zipped = zip(features, labels)
return dict(zipped)
```

but actually I just get inappropriate dict length of data like this :

```
len(zipped) = 150
len(dict) = 147
```

how do I get `len(dict)` equals to `len(zipped)`?

Comment: By not having duplicates in your data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this instead of `return dict(zipped)`:

```
ret = {}
for key, val in zipped:
    if key not in ret:
        ret[key] = val
    else:
        print("Duplicate key: '%s'" % key)
return ret
```

How you want to handle the data loss due to duplicates, that depends on your needs. Maybe rename the key in order to preserve the data, maybe extend the values into a list and accumulate instead of replace, maybe it turns out that it is ok to ignore duplicate keys.

Answer (score 0):

You have duplicates in your data:

```
len(dict(zip(['k1', 'k2', 'k1'], ['v1', 'v2', 'v3']))) == 2
```

When your key array contains duplicate only the last entry will be visible in the final dict.

Answer (score 0):

The key in a dictionary needs to be unique.  To expand on Marcin Pietraszek's aswer:

```
dict(zip(['k1', 'k2', 'k1'], ['v1', 'v2', 'v3']))
```

will return:

```
{'k2' : 'v2', 'k1' : 'v3'}
```

Four of the values in your features variable are the same.